# Cassandra perfomance tuning & JVM Tuning

Tags: java, performance, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I am setting up Cassandra for my staging environment.Gone through lot of docs for Performance tuning and JVM tuning.

But one thing is still not clear :

Keeping memtables out of JVM heap, what should be the size of JVM heap then.
I have **16 GB** of RAM, I was thinking to set 4GB JVM heap and 12 GB off-heap.. Setting memtable as offheap_objects.

Would really appreciate any help here. Thanks in Advance.